# AngularJS approach for parent with multiple child (tab views)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

![Desired sample page][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpLxg.png

I'm writing my first angular application and I have a best practices question.

This is a desktop application where the user 
1. A user filters for requested data
2. The system populates the data grid
3. When a row is selected the tabs are populated based on selected row.

That's the best approach to splitting this into multiple view, directives, controllers etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A few links you may find helpful:

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices